# Nagios with HP Service Manager

Tags: nagios

I´ve been trying to integrate Nagios 3 with HP Service Manager, but without success.

Has anybody done that already?

Can anyone help me please?

Tks

Comment: What does "without success" mean? You should provide more info.

Comment: It'd probably also help to explain what "integrate" means.  You can run them both on the same system trivially, for example, but that may not be what's intended.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this specifically, but I know both Service Manager and Nagios. Getting Nagios to create an incident is pretty straightforward. Try smcli.py (from http://www.ifost.org.au/Software/#smcli ) to create an incident.

The Nagios clear event then needs to trigger a close, but you need to keep track of which incident was previously opened to make this happen. You could either save the output from the incident create and leave it on the Nagios server somewhere so that the close script can find it, or you need to run a search against the Service Manager server to find it.

If you go with the search-and-then-close, then you will need to store "this is an incident which came from Nagios monitoring test XXXX" somewhere on Service Manager (xreference? foreign.id? third.party.reference? Add a custom field?) when you create the incident.

Answer (score 0):

We did it by using the Nagios event handler and a ruby script that called the HPSM soap based web service. Which would open a incident and add a comment to the host in comment with the incident number.

Your best bet is to look at the code published here: http://www.ifost.org.au/Software/soap-course-progs/ and do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Try this plugin out:

http://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_hpasm/

It allows nagios to access SM through various SNMP MIBS.

Comment: he is referring to HP Service Manager. Not HP hardware.